# Entity Framework won't add children to parent object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

The api response returns as if the function ran without problems but when i look the database the row simple is not there.

I don't get any error messages.

Even if I try to add one exam directly through `_context.Exames` it won't add.

I'm getting really frustrated because I don't even know where or what I should look for as the api returns that the method run successfully

I'm using ASP.NET Core 5 and EF Core with MySQL.

Here is the code:

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public List<Exame> Exames { get; set; }
    public List<Consulta> Consultas { get; set; }
}

public class Exame
{
    [Key]
    public int ExameID { get; set; }

    public long Image { get; set; }
}

public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Exame> Exames { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost("exame")]
public IActionResult CreateExame(ExameRequest exame)
{
    _accountService.CreateExame(exame);
    return Ok(new { message = "Exame added successfully" });
}

public void CreateExame(ExameRequest model)
{
    var account = _context.Accounts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.AccountId);

    var exame = new Exame();

    exame.ExameID = model.Id;

    exame.Image = model.Image;

    if (account.Exames == null)
    {
       account.Exames = new List<Exame>();
    }

    account.Exames.Add(exame);

    _context.Accounts.Update(account);

    _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's returning before the Save has finished, try altering it to something like:

```
[HttpPost("exame")]
public Task<IActionResult> CreateExame(ExameRequest exame)
{
    var result = await _accountService.CreateExame(exame);
    // check the value and return the appropriate message.
    return Ok(new { message = "Exame added successfully" });
}

public async Task<int> CreateExame(ExameRequest model)
{
    // removed other code

    return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Since the call to `SaveChangesAsync()` is async, the code is making the call and moving straight back to the api call and returning OK. The result of the SaveChangesAsync is as follows.

> A task that represents the asynchronous save operation. The task
> result contains the number of state entries written to the underlying
> database. This can include state entries for entities and/or
> relationships. Relationship state entries are created for many-to-many
> relationships and relationships where there is no foreign key property
> included in the entity class (often referred to as independent
> associations).

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem as I am following a course.
it is probably a versioning problem, cause my code is exactly the same as the instructor but I can't get the result I want.

I think it is because of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory version.
the 5th version apparently don't have this problem but 7 does.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33454963)